# VariableSizedWrapGrid on an ItemPanelTemplate in WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, variablesizedwrapgrid

On WP8 I Would like to display a list on a page like this :

[image]

I am aware that I can do this easily with WP8.1 and the VariableSizedWrapGrid Control. But I need to make it work on WP8.0. So I try the toolkit from Kinnara : https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit.Kinnara/
Which contains a VariableSizedWrapGrid.

I can do the display that I want (see the screenshot) but I can't use it in a LongListSelector or a ListBox as an ItemPanelTemplate.

Here is the code that I tried (it is inspired from a method that works on Windows 8, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work on WP8) and also from this blog post : http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/09/14/windows-8-xaml-and-displaying-multiple-sized-items.aspx.

```
           <local:SpecificListBox x:Name="LB_Wings" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IT_Wings}" >
                <local:SpecificListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemWidth="100" ItemHeight="100" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4"></toolkit:VariableSizedWrapGrid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </local:SpecificListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <local:SpecificListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="toolkit:VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpan"   Value="{Binding ItemSize}" />
                        <Setter Property="toolkit:VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpan"  Value="{Binding ItemSize}" />
                    </Style>
                </local:SpecificListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </local:SpecificListBox>
```

the data template :

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="IT_Wings">          
            <Grid Margin="0,0,12,12" >
                <Image Source="{Binding BI_List}" Stretch="UniformToFill" </Image>
            </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The SpecificListBox is just a class that inherit ListBox and overridde the PrepareContainerForItemOverride method :

```
class SpecificListBox : ListBox
{
    public SpecificListBox() { }
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(System.Windows.DependencyObject element, object item)
    {    
        dynamic lateBoundItem = item;

        int sizeFactor = (int)lateBoundItem.ItemSize;

        element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, sizeFactor);
        element.SetValue(VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, sizeFactor);  
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

Now in the code behind I just populate LB_Wings with a list of items (that have the ItemSize property) :

```
LB_Wings.ItemsSource = listOfItems; //a list of items that have the ItemSize property.
```

Unfortunately I get the error : "Cannot create Instance of type : SpecificListBox" when I Initialize my page.

I think I 'm close to the solution. Can anyone help me to do this kind of diplay (which seems natural on WP8) but with a ListBox and an ItemPanelTemplate ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is make SpecificListBox a **public** class. :)

```
public class SpecificListBox : ListBox
```

**Edit**

Also, you don't need the bindings in the ItemContainerStyle of the SpecificListBox. I changed those with Horizontal/VerticalContentAlignment = Stretch, because I feel it looks better this way. Without this the control in the DataTemplate does not take all the place for the item. Here's the changed xaml:

```
<local:SpecificListBox x:Name="LB_Wings" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IT_Wings}" >
    <local:SpecificListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemWidth="100" ItemHeight="100" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4"></toolkit:VariableSizedWrapGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </local:SpecificListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <local:SpecificListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </local:SpecificListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</local:SpecificListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get another error on the parsing :" Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Setter.Value'" at this line  :      <Setter Property="toolkit:VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpan"   Value="{Binding ItemSize}" /> I can't find a way to bind my itemSize to a property of this control from the toolkit...

Comment: Well, you don't need that binding. If you use your SpecificListBox, the values that you're trying to bind will be set in the PrepareContainerForItemOverride method. You can use SetBinding instead of SetValue in it, if you want them bound.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you be more specific ? What am I doing wrong in the PrepareContainerForItemOverride method ? Thank you for your help

Comment: I modified the answer a bit. Everyting's okay with the method. The problem was in the ItemContainerStyle. I don't think you can have a Binding in a Setter Value.

Comment: I tried this, I don't have any bug, but all my items are displayed with the same size. And I don't go into the PrepareContainerForItemOverride method. What do I have to do to call the method ?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the SpecificListBox and not a normal ListBox? Clean and redeploy. It should be okay - it's working for me.

Comment: Oh yes, changed it so many times I haven't checked that I forgot to put my SpecificListBox ! :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Shall I get the bounty? :P Or do you have any other questions related to this?

Comment: Yes Sure, But I StackOverflow told me that I can't Give you right now, I have to wait 19 hours. But I will give it to you don't worry :) Thank you again